# Add a photo that pulls from what the user photo has using Adobe Animate and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, adobe, adobe-animate

I am trying to figure out how I can add an agentInfo_photo here in the code. I have tried adding if(agent_photo) but it wont load or pull out from profile and it makes other elements static. Any insights or help would ne appreciated! Thanks

```js
this.frame_952 = function() {
        var main = this;
        
        main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_name.agentInfo_name_txt.text = "";
        main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_titleLicenseDesignation.agentInfo_titleLicenseDesignation_txt.text = "";
        main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_phone1.agentInfo_phone1_txt.text = "";
        main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_phone2.agentInfo_phone2_txt.text = "";
        main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_email.agentInfo_email_txt.text = "";
        main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_url.agentInfo_url_txt.text = "";
        
        if(agent_name || agentInfoStr || agent_phone_1_number || agent_phone_2_number || agent_email || formattedAgentURL){
            
            function addName(){
                if(agent_name){
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_name.agentInfo_name_txt.type(agent_name,56,true,addAgentInfoStr);
                }else{
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_name.visible = false;
                    addAgentInfoStr();
                }
            }
        
            function addAgentInfoStr(){
                if(agentInfoStr){
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_titleLicenseDesignation.agentInfo_titleLicenseDesignation_txt.type(agentInfoStr,56,true,addPhone1);
                }else{
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_titleLicenseDesignation.visible = false;
                    addPhone1();
                }
            }
        
            function addPhone1(){   
                if(agent_phone_1_number){
                    var phone1Str = agent_phone_1_number + " " + agent_phone_1_type;
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_phone1.agentInfo_phone1_txt.type(phone1Str,56,true,addPhone2);
                }else{
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_phone1.visible = false;
                    addPhone2();
                }
            }
        
            function addPhone2(){   
                if(agent_phone_2_number){
                    var phone2Str = agent_phone_2_number + " " + agent_phone_2_type;
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_phone2.agentInfo_phone2_txt.type(phone2Str,56,true,addEmail);
                }else{
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_phone2.visible = false;
                    addEmail();
                }
            }
        
            function addEmail(){        
                if(agent_email){
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_email.agentInfo_email_txt.type(agent_email,56,true,addURL);
                }else{
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_email.visible = false;
                    addURL();
                }
            }
        
            function addURL(){  
                if(formattedAgentURL){
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_url.agentInfo_url_txt.type(formattedAgentURL,56);
                }else{
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_url.visible = false;
                }
            }
                
        }else{
            main.outro.agentInfo.visible = false;
        }
        
        addName();

this.frame_952 = function() {
        var main = this;
        
        main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_name.agentInfo_name_txt.text = "";
        main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_titleLicenseDesignation.agentInfo_titleLicenseDesignation_txt.text = "";
        main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_phone1.agentInfo_phone1_txt.text = "";
        main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_phone2.agentInfo_phone2_txt.text = "";
        main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_email.agentInfo_email_txt.text = "";
        main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_url.agentInfo_url_txt.text = "";
        
        if(agent_name || agentInfoStr || agent_phone_1_number || agent_phone_2_number || agent_email || formattedAgentURL){
            
            function addName(){
                if(agent_name){
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_name.agentInfo_name_txt.type(agent_name,56,true,addAgentInfoStr);
                }else{
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_name.visible = false;
                    addAgentInfoStr();
                }
            }
        
            function addAgentInfoStr(){
                if(agentInfoStr){
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_titleLicenseDesignation.agentInfo_titleLicenseDesignation_txt.type(agentInfoStr,56,true,addPhone1);
                }else{
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_titleLicenseDesignation.visible = false;
                    addPhone1();
                }
            }
        
            function addPhone1(){   
                if(agent_phone_1_number){
                    var phone1Str = agent_phone_1_number + " " + agent_phone_1_type;
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_phone1.agentInfo_phone1_txt.type(phone1Str,56,true,addPhone2);
                }else{
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_phone1.visible = false;
                    addPhone2();
                }
            }
        
            function addPhone2(){   
                if(agent_phone_2_number){
                    var phone2Str = agent_phone_2_number + " " + agent_phone_2_type;
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_phone2.agentInfo_phone2_txt.type(phone2Str,56,true,addEmail);
                }else{
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_phone2.visible = false;
                    addEmail();
                }
            }
        
            function addEmail(){        
                if(agent_email){
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_email.agentInfo_email_txt.type(agent_email,56,true,addURL);
                }else{
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_email.visible = false;
                    addURL();
                }
            }
        
            function addURL(){  
                if(formattedAgentURL){
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_url.agentInfo_url_txt.type(formattedAgentURL,56);
                }else{
                    main.outro.agentInfo.agentInfo_url.visible = false;
                }
            }
                
        }else{
            main.outro.agentInfo.visible = false;
        }
        
        addName();
```